# Can I use part of one beacon pyramid as part of a second pyramid?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I want to have more pyramid powers available than a maxed pyramid can provide, I'd have to build a second pyramid. Can that second pyramid be partially made of blocks that are still within the first pyramid?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, according to the [Minecraft Wiki page on Beacons:](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Beacon#Trivia)

> Adjacent beacons may share blocks in their pyramids, allowing for fairly efficient designs that provide multiple powers.

Here's an example, again from the wiki:

[image]